# how to create a vector from -3000 to 3000 with 128 elements

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

how to create this in c++? this is in matlab. I've searched on google but I couldn't find this out. Can someone who knows this help me?

```
a = linspace(-3000, 3000, 128)
```

this is a vector from -3000 to 3000 with 128 elements.

Comment: what did you try? there is no such function in c++, you need to write the logic yourself

Comment: thanks, I tried to use a `while`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A crude example:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> v(128);     // create new vector with 128 elements

for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)   // init vector with required values
    v[i] = -3000.0 + 6000.0 * i / 127.0;
```

Comment: There's no need for the `static_cast`. Standard C++ promotion rules already imply that behaviour.

Comment: @Kerek SB: yes, good point - I tend to make int<->float casts explicit regardless as a matter of style. I'll edit out the cast in this instance to make the example simpler.